# Adding points to an object without overwriting the existing points

Tags: java, arraylist, addition, overwrite

I'm trying to write a simple program where you will "collect" different objects with points which gives a kind of score. For example, a "Porsche" will be given a point determined by the user and if you enter a new point, that point shall be added onto the old value. So lets say that you give "Porsche" 100 points and then add 50, the total points should be 150. The program should also store a total amount of points for different cars (so if I add an BMW with 100 points the total should be 250(150 points comes from the Porsche)).

First, I look through my ArrayList for the car, but then when I try to add a new score, it just overwrite the existing one with the new value.

```
    System.out.println("The name of the car: ");
    String carName = readString();
    Car car = findCar(carName);

    if(car == null){
        System.out.println("Car doesn't exist!");
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Add more points for the car: ");
    car.setPoints(readInt());
    carlist.add(car);
```

I guess there is an easy way to solve this, but right now I'm clueless and my Googling skills aren't giving me any results.

readInt() and readString() is just methods for my scanners

Comment: `car.setPoints(car.getPoints() + readInt());`?

Comment: or simply create a method  `addPoint(int)`, it is not forbidden, getter and setter are a standard but you can create other methods.

Comment: @IQV Thanks alot! Haha... oh man I wish I would have thought of that... Follow up - it seems that I'm creating duplicates of the same car. The score is updating as it should, but if I add 50, then 100 to the same object I now get 3 of the same cars, but with the same total. What's required for the score to only be added on the same object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a setter here, by definition it replace the value.

You should create a method that simple will add a value to the existing one.

I use a simple syntax for numeric field (pretty standard too) :

```
public void addPoint(int points){
    this.points += points;
}
```

You can do some verification here if you want, refusing negative values or anything else.

EDIT : for the second problem (this should be a different question but this is a small mistake)

You are getting the instance with `Car car = findCar(carName);` and don't do anything if it is null. But after you add some points, you `carlist.add(car);`, so unless you removed it with `findCar`, you add the same instance in this list.

Comment: Thanks alot! Haha... oh man I wish I would have thought of that... 
Duplicated response from another answer:
Follow up - it seems that I'm creating duplicates of the same car. The score is updating as it should, but if I add 50, then 100 to the same object I now get 3 of the same cars, but with the same total. What's required for the score to only be added on the same object?

Comment: @zkulltrail That's a different problem but since you add the car after the update, this seems logic ;) You could simply added a new instance if the findCar return null (instead of exiting the method with return)

Comment: Thanks again! Sorry for all the duplicate answer, still learing this site :)
It worked by just removing carlist.add(car);

Cheers mate!

Comment: @zkulltrail, no need, I just said that one question on SO should be limit to one problem. But this is not necessary here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add a method in `Car` class:

```
public int getPoints(){
    return points;
}
```

Then replace the increment-call:

```
System.out.println("Add more points for the car: ");
car.setPoints(car.getPoints()+readInt());
```